# Angular 2 float label not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template, bootstrap-material-design

when the view is rendered for first time it isn't work until i press F5 to refresh the whole page then it works fine
i am using two way data binding for the input 
this is the property declaration
searchKey:string

Before Refresh

[image: Before Refresh]

After Refresh

[image: After Refresh]

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchKey" class="form-control">
        <label class="form-label">Search</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without knowing the details of where this plugin is from, it is hard for us to determine the issue. This is most likely due to plugin javascript did not initialized for that input control.

Comment: i am using this template https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/index.html